# Run Script over SSH with nologin user

Tags: linux, ssh, user-accounts

I have to run a script from server A and connects to 20 more servers over ssh to pull information. Previously i was using a normal user, and that would become a problem once the password for that user is expired. So i was thinking about using a Service Account to run the Script.

Would it be possible to run the script with a nologin user??

Comment: what is a "nologin" user? if you connect via ssh to a remote server, you either run a shell or some other command. this task has to run with some UID.
consider using x509 certificates rather than passwords, because passwords are for humans running interactive sessions.

Answer (score 0):

As skynats social suggested, using SSH keys solves your problem without the need of nologin user. [HERE](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-ssh-key-based-authentication-on-a-linux-server) you can find a simple tutorial on how to perform the setup.

As you have to pull informations from many servers, I would recommend clustershell. It uses SSH to run the same command on many servers in parallel, and much more. [HERE](https://clustershell.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) you can find the complete documentation.